# How do I get my PHP application to re-use the same window for playing music?

Tags: php, html, xml

Below is the code for my player which will automatically generate a `playlist.xml` file according to the songs selected by the user. I kept this file as `player.php` in my root folder, and in the form I give:

```
<form method="post" action="/player.php" target="_blank">
```

so this player is opening and playing songs according to what is selected.

But the problem is when the user again selects different songs while previously selected songs are playing in the player in new window, the new songs selected are opening in one more window, i.e. now two player windows are opened.

Actually, I want the second selected songs will play in the same window which is already opened.  You can check what's happening in my site by playing songs: http://www.musicking.in/hindi-songs/69.html

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["song"])&& $_POST['song'] != "") {
    $song = $_POST["song"];
  }
  else { $song=array(); }

  for ($i="0"; $i<count($song); $i++) { 
    //echo  $song[$i];
  }

  //start of new php codep
  // create doctype

  //$array = array(
  //  'song.mp3','song.mp3','song.mp3',
  //);

  $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");

  // display document in browser as plain text 
  // for readability purposes
  header("Content-Type: text/plain");
  // create root element
  $root = $dom->createElement("xml");
  $dom->appendChild($root);
  $i = "1";
  foreach ($song as $counter) {
    // create child element
    $song = $dom->createElement("track");
    $root->appendChild($song);

    $song1 = $dom->createElement("path");
    $song->appendChild($song1);
    // create text node
    $text = $dom->createTextNode($counter);
    $song1->appendChild($text); 

    $song1 = $dom->createElement("title");
    $song->appendChild($song1);

    $text = $dom->createTextNode("song ".$i);
    $song1->appendChild($text); 
    $i++;
  }

  // save and display tree
  //echo $dom->saveXML();
  $dom->save("playlist.xml");
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

<div id="flashPlayer">
  This text will be replaced by the flash music player.
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
   var so = new SWFObject("playerMultipleList.swf", "mymovie", "295", "200", "7", "#FFFFFF");  
   so.addVariable("autoPlay","yes")
   so.addVariable("playlistPath","playlist.xml")
   so.write("flashPlayer");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code formatting is broken, some parts even seem missing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only do this with javascript as far as i know ... and theres a small hack to detect if a pop-up was opened and if it did to send javascript requests to it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this probably isn't the "FIX" you are looking for, but try specifying the target in your flash vars.

I think it may help to specify _self

just a thought

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size;)

```
<form method="post" action="/player.php" target="popup-player" target="playerTargetWin" onSubmit="window.open('about:blank','playerTargetWin','width=300,height=300')">
    <p>
        <label for="textfield">Type something in the box:</label>
        <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```